# Error adding libGdx freetype libraries to Android project

Tags: java, libgdx, freetype

I am trying to use the libgdx-freetype libraries that come with LibGDX. For the desktop, I simply added `libgdx-freetype.jar` and `libgdx-natives.jar` to the `/libs` folder of the main project (and added to build path) and it just worked. However, when trying to add the same libraries to `/libs` folder and the `libgdx-freetype.so` files to the `/libs/armeabi` and `/libs/armeabi-v7a` folders, I get the build error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Native libraries detected in 'gdx-freetype-natives.jar'. See console for more information.  
SlotMachine-android     Unknown Android Packaging Problem
```

In the Eclipse console I have:

```
[2012-12-05 17:38:04 - SlotMachine-android] The library 'gdx-freetype-natives.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
[2012-12-05 17:38:04 - SlotMachine-android] The following libraries were found:
[2012-12-05 17:38:04 - SlotMachine-android]  - libgdx-freetype.so
[2012-12-05 17:38:04 - SlotMachine-android]  - libgdx-freetype64.so
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Android you do not want gdx-freetype-natives.jar included. That is only for your main project. On Android you just need gdx-freetype.jar and the two .so files in your arm folders. The .so files are the natives for Android.